# Connect to the host localhost interface from a VirtualBox guest

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Windows machine with service running on `127.0.0.1:9000`. In VirtualBox I have a Linux guest and I'd like to access the Windows localhost service.

In VirtualBox I have a NAT networking and I configured port forwarding `127.0.0.1:9000` → `10.0.2.15:9000`. Firewall is disabled on both systems. On host system telnet `127.0.0.1 9000` works fine, but on guest system `telnet 10.0.2.15 9000` returns *Connection refused*.

In VBox.log I can see that the port forwarding rule has been applied:

```
00:00:06.261834 [/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/PortForwarding/] (level 6)
00:00:06.261835
00:00:06.261835 [/Devices/e1000/0/LUN#0/Config/PortForwarding/0/] (level 7)
00:00:06.261836   BindIP    <string>  = "127.0.0.1" (cb=10)
00:00:06.261837   GuestIP   <string>  = "10.0.2.15" (cb=10)
00:00:06.261837   GuestPort <integer> = 0x0000000000002328 (9 000)
00:00:06.261838   HostPort  <integer> = 0x0000000000002328 (9 000)
00:00:06.261838   Name      <string>  = "Rule 1" (cb=7)
00:00:06.261839   Protocol  <string>  = "TCP" (cb=4)
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this kind of port forwarding even possible?

Comment: I suppose what you want is to redirect traffics from the guest to the host destined at `10.0.2.2:9000` to (the host's) `127.0.0.1:9000`. IIRC that's possible in Linux, but no idea about Windows. (Either way you won't be setting it up in/with VirtualBox but components of the host OS itself.)